Convert textarea input separated by commas to List
I have a form and in there I got a textarea where materials should be separated by a comma.
  <div class="mb-3">
      <label class="form-label" for="material">Materiaal</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="material" name="material"
         placeholder="scheid je materiaal met een komma"></textarea>
  </div>

Now when it's been sent to my controller I always get the error: 'There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Validation failed for object='artwork'. Error count: 1'
My controller looks like this:
    @PostMapping("/artworknew")
    public String newArtworkPost(Model model,
                                 @Valid Artwork artwork, Principal principal,
                                 BindingResult bindingResult, @RequestParam Integer assignment,
                                 @RequestParam(required = false) MultipartFile image,
                                 @RequestParam(required = false) Integer inspiration,
                                 @RequestParam(required = false) String inspirationName,
                                 @RequestParam(required = false) String inspirationUrl,
                                 @RequestParam(required = false) String material) throws IOException {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("assignments", assignmentRepository.findAll());
            return "student/artworknew";
        }
        Account account = accountRepository.findByUsername(principal.getName()).get();
        artwork.setAccounts(account);
        


        if (!material.isEmpty()) {
            List<String> materialList = Arrays.asList(material.split(", "));
            for (String m : materialList) {
                Material newMaterial = new Material();
                newMaterial.setArtwork(artwork);
                newMaterial.setMaterialName(m);
                materialsRepository.save(newMaterial);
            }
        }
        artworkRepository.save(artwork);
        return "redirect:/student/ownart";
    }

What can be the reason for this error? I don't see how it could be solved.

I guess the error you described is perceived on client side. What data are you sending it? Is there something in the server logs?

Don't look too much at material. The error is about artwork. And that has an @Valid annotation.
